# Twilio Webhook with Postman request

Tags: node.js, curl, twilio, postman

I can't set StatusCallback to a message in Postman. 
From **[this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages)** page I copied cURL code, imported to Postman, added authorization (it's Basic Auth), messages are sent from Twilio number to specified in "To" number. Everything works except for Webhook. As I see (by link above) there should be a "**status_callback**" field in response after sending a message, but it does not exist. My response is:

```
{
    "sid": "SomeLongMessageId",
    "date_created": "Mon, 20 Aug 2018 09:08:04 +0000",
    "date_updated": "Mon, 20 Aug 2018 09:08:04 +0000",
    "date_sent": null,
    "account_sid": "myaccountsid",
    "to": "+9XXXXXXXXXX3",
    "from": "+14XXXXXXXX5",
    "messaging_service_sid": null,
    "body": "Where is webhook?",
    "status": "queued",
    "num_segments": "1",
    "num_media": "0",
    "direction": "outbound-api",
    "api_version": "2010-04-01",
    "price": null,
    "price_unit": "USD",
    "error_code": null,
    "error_message": null,
    "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/myaccountsid/Messages/SomeLongMessageId.json",
    "subresource_uris": {
        "media": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/myaccountsid/Messages/SomeLongMessageId/Media.json"
    }
}
```

Made the same thing in the code - just like in manual at the link above (Node.js):

```
const client = require('twilio')('myAccountSid', 'myAuthToken');
const sms = {
    body: 'Will webhook work?', from: '+14XXXXXXXX5',
    statusCallback: 'http://postb.in/b/BC1prY1s', to: '+9XXXXXXXXX13'
};
client.messages.create(sms).then(res => console.log(res)).done();
```

Same response with no "status_callback" key. I don't know, may be webhooks must be activated somewhere in Twilio account settings or what?
P.S. why the topic is changed to "Node.js - my question"? I want it to be "Twilio - My question", but tags are in the order I can't change. And topic prefix is after node.js tag

[image: Postman request screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, looks like webhooks work even if they are not mentioned in response. I've looked into Twilio errors, it was telling that http://postb.in/b/XxXxXxXx was not reachable. And it is OK after 30 minutes of postb.in's bin existence.
Don't know why it was making webhooks after more than 30 minutes, though.
And also don't know why there is something in docs, but it doesn't exist in response.